# An apparent counterexample to Lusin's theorem

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples, measurable-functions

[image]

What is a compact set $A⊂I$ that satisfies the Lusin's theorem statement about $f$ for $ε > 0$?

Comment: Saying a function defined on $I$ is continuous on $A \subset I$ does not mean that $f$ is continuous at every point of $A$.  Indeed, consider the characteristic function of the rationals.  It is discontinuous everywhere, but if $A$ is the irrationals, then $f$ is continuous on $A$, since it is constant on $A$.

Comment: @GEdgar I'm pretty sure OP knows that, it even says that $f$ is discontinuous everywhere in the quoted text. The question is specific and has a specific answer

Comment: Please upload this question to this site. The link behind it is likely to disappear in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Choose compact sets $A_1\subset E, A_2\subset E^c$ with the appropriate Lusin property. Then $\chi_{A_1}$ is continuous on $A_1\cup A_2.$

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a hint, and leads to the answer pretty easily.

Comment: At the stage $n$ of constructing $E$, the set $I-E_n$ is a countable union of open intervals. Setting $A_1=E_n$ and $A_2$ equal to the union of the compact sets (with the length $(1-\epsilon_n)$ times the open interval containing it) will work for large enough n.